# Importing and Exporting a GIF Slows Its Speed?

Tags: gif-format

I have a GIF on my machine that I have imported via

```mathematica
gifLst = Import["/path/to/my/file.gif"]
```

When I then export it to the cloud, it gets slowed down in its animation speed:

```mathematica
CloudExport[gifLst, "GIF", "cloud/path/file.gif", Permissions -> "Public"]
```

Is there a way to retain the animation speed when importing and re-exporting like this?

##### Original GIF (normal speed)

[image: Original GIF (normal speed)]

##### Wolfram imported GIF (slowed speed)

[image: Wolfram imported GIF (slowed speed)]

Original GIF

Answer (score 6):

Maybe extract `"DisplayDurations"` from the original gif.

```
gif = Import["https://s3.gifyu.com/images/12th_NUC.gif"];
durations = 
 Import["https://s3.gifyu.com/images/12th_NUC.gif", 
  "DisplayDurations"];
Export["test.gif", gif, "DisplayDurations" -> durations]
SystemOpen["test.gif"]
```